# Notation confusion: are $\Gamma(U, O_x)$ and $\Gamma(U, O_x|_U)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am wondering, given a scheme $(X,O_X)$ and $U \subseteq X$ an open subset, are $\Gamma(U, O_X)$ and $\Gamma(U, O_X|_U)$ the same? I think they are not, but why? Shouldn't they both assigned the open set $U$ the same ring?

Edit:I am particularly confused by this: Let $S = \oplus S_n$ a graded ring. Let X=$\text{Proj}(S)$ and $f\in S_d$, then $\Gamma(D_+(f), O_X) = \{g/f^m | g\in S_{md}, m\geq 0\}$, and so the RHS = $(S_f)_0$ (the degree 0 part of $S_f$). Now let $S_{(f)} = (S_f)_0$. Then the example says that $\Gamma(D_+(f), O_X|_{D_+(f)})=\text{Spec}S_{(f)}$ instead of just $S_{(f)}$.

Comment: Do you have the definition of $O_X|_U$ handy? This will help you greatly in your efforts.

Comment: @KReiser The definition is that for open subset $V \subseteq U$, $O_X|_U(V) = O_X(V)$.

Comment: So when you apply that definition to $V=U$, what happens?

Comment: @KReiser The way that I asked the question seems rather silly...I edited the question with an example.

Comment: "The example says that" : what example ? And you can see that it is clearly a typo, on the LHS you have a ring, on the RHS you have a scheme

Comment: @Max So I guess it should be just $(D_+(f), O_X|_{D_+(f)}) = \text{Spec}(S_{(f)})$?

Comment: Yes, that's much more reasonable, and in fact it's true (it's part of the proof that $Proj(S)$ is a scheme)